# Does session function is needed to run wordpress and how to configure it?

Tags: php, php.ini

DO you think wordpress need php function enabled so that it will run properly and securely?

I have setup the session like this :

```
session.auto_start      = Off
session.save_path       = /tmp/phpsession
session.name            = JARENGGONSESSION
session.hash_function   = 1 
session.hash_bits_per_character = 6
session.use_trans_sid   = 0
session.cookie_domain   = domain.com
#session.cookie_path     = /application/path/
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_secure   = On
session.cookie_httponly = 1
session.use_only_cookies= 1
session.cache_expire    = 30
default_socket_timeout  = 60
```

When I check using this script :

```
<?php
// Start Session
session_start();
// Show banner
echo '<b>Session Support Checker</b><hr />';
// Check if the page has been reloaded
if(!isset($_GET['reload']) OR $_GET['reload'] != 'true') {
   // Set the message
   $_SESSION['MESSAGE'] = 'Session support enabled!<br />';
   // Give user link to check
   echo '<a href="?reload=true">Click HERE</a> to check for PHP Session Support.<br />';
} else {
   // Check if the message has been carried on in the reload
   if(isset($_SESSION['MESSAGE'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['MESSAGE'];
   } else {
      echo 'Sorry, it appears session support is not enabled, or you PHP version is to old. <a href="?reload=false">Click HERE</a> to go back.<br />';
   }
}
?>
```

the php session is not enabled

Comment: Wordpress Core doesn't use sessions (as far as I am aware) but plugins may. So it likely depends on whatever add-ons you are running on your site.

Comment: So what benefit I get when running php session on, then use it on the plugin I install.

Comment: Good question. That would likely depend entirely on the specific plugin.